# Missing OpenGL.GL model

Tags: python, pygame, pyopengl

I am trying to run this code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Abood/Documents/lol.py", line 3, in <module>
    from OpenGL.GL import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenGL.GL'
```

I tried removing the .GL part and this came up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/Abood/Documents/lol.py", line 4, in <module> from OpenGL.GLU import * ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenGL.GLU'
```

Comment: Have you installed the module? By the way, only the first 4 lines of your code are relevant to your question. That's where the error happens. Please remove the irrelevant code, save out time and effort.

Comment: Yes I have downloaded the module, but I don't know if I downloaded it properly

Comment: BTW what module is it, is it the pygame or pyopenGL

Comment: I tried removing the .GL part and this came up: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Abood/Documents/lol.py", line 4, in <module>
    from OpenGL.GLU import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenGL.GLU'

Comment: Did you follow the [installation instructions](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Please don't add details in comments, since they cannot be formatted properly. You can edit your question if you have additional information that will make the question more clear.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry I am just new here :)

Comment: Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to use Stack Overflow. It'll take only a few minutes! Your comment about 5 comments above this one (the one with the error if you remove the .GL part) is difficult to read because it's all on one line, without formatting. And people that only read the question will miss this information. It's better to add it to your question if it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install both the pygame and OpenGL packages. The easiest way is using `pip`:

```
pip install pygame
pip install PyOpenGL
```

This worked for me. After installing the packages and running your code, I got:

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
```

There are also different ways to install the OpenGL module. See the [installation instructions on the PyOpenGL website](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/installation.html).